# Let $(a_0 = a_1 = a_2 = 2)$ and $(a_n = a_{n-1} + a_{n-2} + a_{n-3})$ for $(n > 3)$. Prove, using strong math induction, that $(a_n < 2^{n+2})$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, inequality, induction

I am unsure if this is correct. Any help/ guidance is appreciated!

We first verify that the inequality holds for the initial values of the sequence, which are $a_0 = a_1 = a_2 = 2$

$$P(0) = 2 < 4$$
$$P(1) = 2 < 8$$
$$P(2) = 2 < 16$$

*Show that for every integer $k \geq 2$, if $P(i)$ is true for
each integer $i$ from $0$ through $k$, then $P(k+1)$ is true*:

Let $k$ be any integer with $k \geq 2$, and suppose that $a_i \leq i$ for each integer $i$ with $0 \leq i \leq k$.

We must show that
$$a_{k+1} < 2^{(k+1) + 2}$$

Now

$$a_{k+1} = a_k + a_{k-1} + a_{k-2}$$
$$= 2^{k+2} + 2^{k+1} + 2^{k}$$
$$= 2^k * 2^2 + 2^k * 2 + 2^k$$
$$= 2^k(2^2 * 2)$$
$$= 2^{k+3}$$

Thus $a_{k+1} < 2^{(k+1) + 2}$

Comment: Your proof is fine except a $<$ sign which must be replaced with $=$ between $2^{k+2} + 2^{k+1} + 2^{k}$ and $ 2^k * 2^2 + 2^k * 2 + 2^k,$ and between $2^k(2^2 * 2)$ and $2^{k+3}.$ And a typo in the last line: replace $a_k+1$ with $a_{k+1}.$

Comment: Also, although we all guess it, you should define the symbol $P$ before using it.

Comment: With the inequality strictly less than instead of less than or equal to is the conclusion of the proof still valid?

Comment: You should not have replaced all $<$ signs with =. Only the two I mentionned. As for your question: ??? yes! (you proved it).

Answer (score 1):

The first version of your proof was nearly correct, but the current version is slightly flawed. Here is the corrected version. Let $a_n = a_{n - 1} + a_{n - 2} + a_{n - 3}$ and $a_0,a_1,a_2 = 2$. We prove that $a_n < 2^{n + 2}$, $\forall n \geq 0$. The inequality holds for the three base cases:

$$a_0 = 2 < 2^2 = 4$$
$$a_1 = 2 < 2^3 = 8$$
$$a_2 = 2 < 2^4 = 16$$

Now we consider $n \geq 2$:

$$a_{n + 1} = a_n + a_{n - 1} + a_{n - 2}$$
$$ < 2^{n + 2} + 2^{n + 1} + 2^{n}$$
$$ = 2^n \left( 2^2 + 2 + 1 \right) = 7\cdot2^n$$
$$< 8 \cdot 2^n = 2^n \left( 2^3 \right) = 2^{n + 3}$$

And so we conclude that $a_{n + 1} < 2^{n + 3}$ and since the three base cases hold it follows from strong induction that $a_n < 2^{n + 2}$, $\forall n \geq 0$.